# I am getting an invalid syntax and a model not defined

Tags: syntax, model

```
epochs = 20
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 2, activation='relu', input_shape = x_train[0].shape))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Droupout(0.5)

model.add(Conv1D(64, 2, activation='relu'))  <<<<"Invalid Syntax"
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Droupout(0.5)
  
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Droupout(0.5)

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()  <<<<"Model not defined"
```

This code is from jupyter notebook.  I have indicated my code issues in the quotations above.  I would appreciate the help.  Thanks!

Comment: Provide the full error message and traceback. Is the string `"Invalid Syntax"` and `"Model not defined"` a part of your actual program? If not, then remove them and provide the actual code. Also, do you have any imports? And make sure to specify language, as it's not possible to say anything about syntax without it.

Comment: Also, don't ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66700989/6486738) multiple times. When you edit your old question, it will be put up on the review queue and reopened if it looks okay.

Comment: Make sure to count your parenthesis. For every opening parenthesis `(` there should be a closing parenthesis `)`. You're missing several closing parenthesis.